# How to count empty cells only if another associated cell is a text values?

Tags: worksheet-function

I have the following table,

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Patient | Date |
| Alex | 1/1/2023 |
| Cody | (blank) |

where I want to count blank cells only if there's text value in the associated cell in column A...

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise this question is likely to be closed due to lack of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is how you want it.

[image]

Count in E2

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISBLANK(C2:C12))*(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B12))))
```

Comment: Yes it worked!! thank you...i've been struggling with this for hours

Comment: One caveat with `ISBLANK()` if there are formulas in the cells that return an empty string (`""`) then ISBLANK will not work here as it will return FALSE.  For those instances (and this one too): `=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C12="")*(B2:B12<>""))`

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A6,"<>",B2:B6,"")
```

only counts rows where both: A is not blank, and B is blank
[image]

returns `2`